# How to remove a specific directory from GitHub using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I've looked all around for a few days now trying to figure this out because our .gitignore even though it lists /bin/ folder it still keeps freaking commiting the whole folder and its getting annoying.

Now we have a whole bunch of crap in a /bin/ folder in our GitHub repository and I have no idea how to remove it.  I've tried looking at other peoples examples but they keep talking about a shell command that I don't have in eclipse (or at least don't know how to access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sad news is that if a file has been already committed to GitHub, `git` will continue to version that file.

This means if I commit the entire `bin/` then add it to `.gitignore`, the files will still persist in GitHub. And, if these files in `bin/` change, they will also be pushed in the commit because they are versioned.

Luckily, you can remove files and directories from GitHub completely. You need, though, to get to a command line running `git`. If you have the GitHub application installed, that probably means you have `git`.

Open command prompt in Windows or Terminal in Mac OS.

Navigate to the directory (ie. `cd ~/Workspace/Project`) and run the following:

```
git rm bin/* -f
git commit --amend
git push -f
```

This should work. Check out [this article on the GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) that also outlines the process.

Hope this helps you!

> Disclaimer: always make sure you do your research before working with `git`. If you have various branches / other complicated stuff going on, this process might be different